# XAML SampleData Binding to Values of a List of Strings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

OK, so I've searched and searched and searched, and I can't find an answer to this specific angle of my question.  I know how to bind to a List, and how to make it auto-updating by making it an ObservableCollection instead of a List.  However, with just a list of Strings, how the heck to I bind to the value of each List element?

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PageTiles">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
              Margin="6,0,6,12">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           Margin="6,0,0,6" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here's the LongListSelector that pulls from the list:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60">
        <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding PageTitles}"
                                LayoutMode="Grid"
                                GridCellSize="150,150"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PageTiles}"
                                SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

Now, I've used a similar layout before to do tiles based off a List of classes that have string properties, but never with a List of strings, and I can't find anything to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried that code? As far as I can see, it will work. `Text={Binding}` should do the trick

Comment: I haven't tried it live yet because it's not working in the design preview.  Am I doing it wrong?  Here's what I have in the sample data file:
`<vm:SoundModel.PageTitles>
 <sys:String>Mario</sys:String>
 <sys:String>Torgue</sys:String>
 <sys:String>Misc</sys:String>
</vm:SoundModel.PageTitles>`

Comment: @har07 OK, so I rebuilt to get the manifests worked out, and I get three tiles now listed in the designer preview, but the text fields are blank, not pulling from the list values.  So it sees that there are three list values now, but not what those values are.

Comment: Sorry, I rarely provide design data when develop WP apps so I can't help about it, maybe somebody else around here can. But as I stated above, your binding statement seems correct already, at least at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out @har07 was right.  The `Text="{Binding}"` I'd put in the text value was valid, my cell size was just too large for it to show in the 60 high grid that I'd made.  Reduced the height of it to less than the stack panel's height and bam, there it was.  I didn't even do that on purpose, that's just how I'd left it while I didn't  know what to put in there, and because I hadn't recompiled to get the associations fixed, it wasn't finding anything to put in as elements.

So, to recap, to get the values of a List directly instead of something that's part of that value, a simple "{Binding}" does the trick.  Lesson learned: double check your size values before running for help XD.